# Put a space before emojis

Tags: r

I am trying to clean up some text. I have a list of emojis that I do not want removed from the text. I would like to put a space before these emojis only if there is not one already.

```
emojis = as.character(outer(c(":", ";", ":-", ";-","="),c(")", "(", "]", "[", "D", "o", "O", "P", "p","8"),FUN = paste,sep=""))
```

If I had a tweet that said.

```
Tweet = "I am so happy:)"
```

I would like that to be

```
Tweet = "I am so happy :)"
```

after the code is run.

It's a pretty simple idea, I haven't been able to find any code to do this though.

Full list of emojis that need a space before them:

```
 ":)"  ";)"  ":-)" ";-)" "=)"  ":("  ";("  ":-(" ";-(" "=("  ":]"  ";]"  ":-]" ";-]" "=]"  ":["  ";["  ":-[" ";-[" "=["  ":D"  ";D"  ":-D" ";-D" "=D"  ":o" ";o"  ":-o" ";-o" "=o"  ":O"  ";O"  ":-O" ";-O" "=O"  ":P"  ";P"  ":-P" ";-P" "=P"  ":p"  ";p"  ":-p" ";-p" "=p"  ":8"  ";8"  ":-8" ";-8" "=8"
```

Comment: How do you get the tweet `Tweet = "I am so happy:)"` ?

Comment: @RonakShah Sorry, maybe that was unclear, the tweet only says "I am so happy:)" The text is just named Tweet.

Comment: @Hack-R - how is this not a reproducible example? The list of emojis is defined in R code, an example of the current data is given in R code, and an intended output is provided. If only all questions here were the same.

Comment: @thelatemail It sounded to me like he was doing sentiment analysis with a package and needed this whitelisted when he cleaned the tweets.  Apparently not but he's saying sentiment analysis and bag of words then the question doesn't have anything to do with it. If the answers have the correct understanding of what he needs then this is a dupe anyway.

Comment: @Hack-R Right, I guess mentioning that it was for sentiment analysis was unnecessary. I am removed that. All I need help with is cleaning the text.

Comment: @akrun Thanks, that one works as well. Did not realize this was so easy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A regular expression can help.

```
emojis = as.character(outer(c(":", ";", ":-", ";-","="),c("\\)", "\\(", "\\]", "\\[", "D", "o", "O", "P", "p","8"),FUN = paste,sep=""))
pat <- paste0("(\\w+)(", paste(emojis, collapse="|"), ")")
Tweet = "I am so happy:)"
sub(pat, "\\1 \\2", Tweet)
#[1] "I am so happy :)"
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. That almost does what I want. The list of emojis also has emojis that start with ; and = though, and this code wont' work for that. How do I incorporate that into  the sub?

Comment: Edited. And a note, I added backslashes to the emojis that needed them.

Comment: Thanks, this is perfect.